# How not to show transpiled files in Chrome Developer Tools when Ctrl + O

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Both original & transpiled files are displayed when opening a file. I'd like only to show original files (Firefox dev tools do this). Possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox 23+ has the option to show original sources instead of transpiled scripts:

[image: FF show original sources]

Unfortunately, it seems you cannot enjoy this in Chrome. You can enable script mapping, or not, but you will always see the actual included files that are included in the source HTML file.

All of these tutorials and references seem to agree:

- [Source Maps 101](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/source-maps-101--net-29173) (Chrome, Windows)

[image: Both files shown]

- [Source Maps With CoffeeScript and Uglify.js](http://tarantsov.com/WorkflowThu/source-maps-with-coffeescript-and-uglify-js/) (Chrome, OSX)

[image: Both files shown]

- [Using Source Maps with TypeScript](http://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2012-10-03-typescript-source-maps.html) (Chrome, Windows)

[image: Both files shown]

- [The Breakpoint Ep 3: The Sourcemap Spectacular with Paul Irish and Addy Osmani](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=HijZNR6kc9A) (Chrome Developers video)

[image: Source and mapped files are shown]

- [Source Maps in Chrome Dev Tools](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-source-maps)

[image: Source and mapped files are shown]

- [Enhance your JavaScript debugging life](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2014/08/22/enhance-your-javascript-debugging-life-thanks-to-the-source-map-support-available-in-ie11-chrome-opera-amp-firefox.aspx) (Chrome, Windows)

[image: Both original and compiled versions appear]

---

It seems that if one really wants to hide the transpiled JavaScript files in DevTools, FireFox is the way to go for now (as of Chrome Canary 49).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It confirms what I orginally thought ;-)
Maybe there is some place to ask for this improvment ?

Answer (score 0):

The goal of a source map is to be able get readable original code so if you don't want it, just don't generate the source map or delete the .js.map file (or make it unreachable on production site).

Answer (score 0):

There is an "Enable JavaScript source maps" option in Chrome Dev Tools' Settings (under "Sources") - does unsetting that option help?